# awk + run awk command without output from pipe line

Tags: linux, bash, awk

the target of the following code is to verify if the **free memory** is less then 20% of the **total memory**

in case fr**ee memory** less then awk should print FAIL otherwise awk will print ok

```
TOTALM=120000K
FREEM=89111K
```

please advice what wrong in this syntax? ,  why I cant run awk as displayed here?

```
awk -v FREEM=$FREE_MEMORY -v TOTALM=$TOTAL_MEMORY '{per=int(FREEM)/int(TOTALM)*100; if(per<=20) print "FAIL" ; else print "OK"}'
```

Comment: This is not a code refactoring service.  What have you tried?  Maybe migrate to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Add `BEGIN` between `'` and `{` and check your variable names.

Comment: can you please write your answer ( with full details ) so I will vote for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of problems in your code:

Firstly, you have changed the names of your two variables when passing them into `awk`.

Secondly, `awk` needs an input file after the script, but you can get around that requirement by putting your code inside a `BEGIN` block.

```
#!/bin/bash
TOTALM=120000K
FREEM=89111K
awk -v FREEM=$FREEM -v TOTALM=$TOTALM '
           BEGIN {per=int(FREEM)/int(TOTALM)*100
                  if(per<20) print "FAIL"
                  else print "OK"}'
```

Comment: Nice! I edited to have a better view of the `awk` command. Also, I feel very flattered to be mentioned in your profile page  :) It's a pleasure to have you around.

Comment: Likewise! I hope @mpapec is equally flattered :-)